# DAL: DataContext principles understanding

Tags: c#, architecture, orm, data-access-layer

Not sure if there's a "offical" name, but by DataContext I mean an object which transparently maintains objects' state, providing change tracking, statement-of-work functionality, concurrency and probably many other useful features. (In Entity Framework it's ObjectContext, in NHibernate - ISession).

Eventually I've come to an idea that something like that should be implemented in my application (it uses mongodb as back-end, and mongodb's partial updates are fine when we're able to track a certain property change).

So actually, I've got several questions on this subject

1. Could anyone formulate requirements to DataContext? - what's your understanding of it's tasks and responsibilities? (The most relevant I've managed to find is Esposito's book, but unfortunately that's at about msdn samples level).
2. What would you suggest for changes tracking implementation? (In simplest way it's possible to track changes "manually" in entities, but requires coding and mixes dal with business logic, so I mostly interested in "automatic" way, keeping entities more poco).
3. Is there way to utilize some existing solution? (I hoped nhibernate infrastructure would allow plugging-in custom module to work with mongo behind the scene, but not sure if it allows working with non-sql dbs at all).

Comment: Get a copy of Fowler's "Patters of Enterprise Application Architecture". It covers Repository, Unit of Work, and other relevant patterns in detail.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of patterns details, the main thing is that how to unite all of those abstractions in scope of "data context".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataContext (ObjectContext or DbContext in EF) is nothing else than an implementation of the [Unit of Work (UoW)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)/[Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern.

I suggest you Fowler's book on [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html) in which he outlines the implementation of several persistency patterns. That might be a help in implementing your own solution.

1. A DataContext basically needs to fullfil the job of a UoW. It needs to handle the reading and management of objects that are involved in a given lifecycle (i.e. HTTP request), s.t. there are no two objects in memory that represent the same record on the DB. Moreover it needs to provide some change tracking for performing partial updates to the DB (as you already mentioned).
2. To what regards change tracking, I fully agree that polluting properties with change events etc is bad. One of the recent templates introduced in EF4.1 uses Proxies to handle that and to give the possibility to have plain POCOs.

Comment: _introduced in EF4.1 uses Proxies to handle that_  
 
Maybe you know, is it possible to use those proxies out of EF environment?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. These proxies are created totally dynamically behind the scenes. Try to search Google for "Entity Framework 4.1 POCO Proxies" or something similar.

Comment: Btw, also from what you say about objects in memory, I suppose there should be also an Identity map. And what also concerns me is that I've got already a couple of repositories (per entity) implemented. What would be your suggestion - making DataContext to be facade for them or generalizing repositories into a single class?

Comment: Sure, Identity map might be an issue as well. Try to look at the Unit of Work pattern. I strongly recommend you the PoEAA book I suggested. It outlines all those persistence and architectural issues quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to quetion 2: To make POCO classes work, you will need to generate code at run-time, possibly using System.Reflection.

If you analyse EntityFramework, you will see that it requires virtual properties to do change-tracking... that is because it needs to create a generated class at run-time, that overrides each property, and then adds code to tell the DataContext when someone changes that property.

EntityFramework also generates code to initialize collections, so that when someone try to do operations like Add and Remove, the collection object itself knows what to do.

Comment: Ok, so I'd be able to generate a derived type which overrides virtual properties and tracks changes. Not sure about collections. Probably, it would be possible if property/field is declared as ICollection - just substituting field by my ICollection implementation. But if it's declared as List? What do you think?

Comment: If it is a List, then you will have to find out wich elements were added or remove by the time you save changes using the DataContext, because you have to compare the original list of elements, with the list that was changed and determine wich elements to update, insert or delete the element.

Comment: Well.. that's so easy, why didn't I think about that before? Thanks)